# Query with ordering on a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, query-performance

I have a table T with a PK Id , two fields FieldA, FieldB and a Date field.

I execute a request (on SQLServer) :

```
select top(N) *
from T 
where (FieldA=Value1 OR FieldB=Value2) AND Date < GivenDate 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

If i have the following two indexes on table :

- `(FieldA ASC)`
- `(FieldB ASC)`

The request "doesn't perform very well" if there are many occurrences of Value1 or Value2 because there is no information about the Date and the engine must read all the matching rows and sort.

I decided to change the indexes to:

- `(FieldA ASC, Date DESC)`
- `(FieldB ASC, Date DESC)`

But it doesn't change anything: the "Actual number of row read" is the total number of rows matching values.

I imagined the engine would be smart enough to get at most N rows from each Indexes and sort (I guess)?

Is it able to do it BUT it's cost based estimation is low enough to decide to use this execution plan ?

Surely not so easy for the engine to guess. But is there an other way to improve this kind of request?

Comment: Thanks . Corrected .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand using SQL Management Studio to check the best index use. It helps a lot.
First, I would put the Date in first position as it is the most used (even if it changes nothing in this case).

Second, if you could do the order in code behind, I would recommand it. Anytime you can, order the result in the code (Java, C#...). I will be much faster and you will have a better use of your indexes as you won't need the index on Date.

Third, if you can't order in the Java or C# code, sometimes, it is better to create your select with no order, put the result into a temporary table with an index on the date and then select from this temporary table with the order. You should look at the execution plan to see which is best.

Then, you could try too is the use of included indexes instead of multiple columns indexes. Something like :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MYINDEX
ON T(Date)
INCLUDED (FieldA, FieldB)
```

I hope this will help. If possible, post your execution plan for us to be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: This is a good idea. "Inverting" the index design with Date indexed and the fields as included columns is a good compromise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that one or more indexes are being used?

If you verify that they are not being used (which is what I think), force at least one of them with **From T with (INDEX (Index_name-here)) ...**
If you want to force both indexes you will have to do an innerjoin against the same table and set the second index there.

Anyway, the best way to solve this is to index on primitive types, which in your case was equivalent to converting the date to an integer.

For this you have three alternatives, do it in the query, do it in a view or add some necessary fields to your structure along with the necessary code to fill in this data automatically in each Insert or Update.

Regards

Comment: Yes but when the plan uses these two indexes the "Actual number of rows" on the Index_Seek operators may be very high compared to N ( for example N : 200 ,  Value 11 Millions) . 

Just makes me think the engine ignores it would be sufficient to return only N rows for each Index_Seek..

Comment: Uhm is not a very large table (and it's narrow). Anyway if you want to get a good performance the best approach would be to index with integers in a view.

Comment: This is a large table the sample i gave was just one sample of match. The table has more than 500M rows and is > 500Gb large.

Comment: OK, 500MRows is really large (i'd read 11M). Did you try "to index with integers in a view" as mentioned previously?